# How to assert that json property is greater than 0 using jsonpath and hamcrest?

Tags: java, spring, hamcrest

I have a JSON response looking like this

```
{
"stockId": 1,
"stockName": "SPOT",
"stockValue": 150.00
}
```

I must ensure that "stockValue" is greater than 0. I tried doing this:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.stockValue"), Matchers.greaterThan(0.00));
```

But that produces me a compile time error of this:

```
'andExpect(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher)' in 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions' cannot be applied to '(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers, org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Double>)'
```

I searched around, and I tried this solution which doesn't work:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.stockValue"), Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.greaterThan(0.00)));
```

Because it produces this compile time error:

```
'andExpect(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher)' in 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions' cannot be applied to '(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers, org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.lang.Double>>)'
```

I want to ensure that stockValue is indeed more than 0.00. How would I do that?

This is my entire test function below:

```
    @Test
    void getStockDetail200() throws Exception {
//          Perform the GET request
        String endpoint = MessageFormat.format("{0}?symbol=SPOT&{1}",
                Utils.BASE_URL,
                Utils.TOKEN);

        mockMvc.perform(get(endpoint)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.stockName", Matchers.is("SPOT")))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.stockValue"), Matchers.greaterThan(0.00));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going to spot this yourself for sure:

> jsonPath("$.stockName", Matchers.is("SPOT"))

vs.

> jsonPath("$.stockValue"), Matchers.greaterThan(0.00)